# Difference of these Linked List approaches

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently studying Linked List in different sites, one is at geeksforgeeks and the other one is at beginnersbook. I am getting confused because the approach in geeksforgeeks is very hard to understand, while on the other hand, beginnersbook is very easy to understand, can someone inform me what's the difference?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, the approach in geeksforgeeks is manual linkedlist while beginnersbook is using linkedlist library, is that correct?

**Here's what I'm saying**

**GeeksforGeeks Approach:**

```
public class LinkedList{
        Node head;

        static class Node{
            int data;
            Node next;

            Node (int d){
                data = d;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        public static void main (String [] args){

            LinkedList list = new List();
            list.head  = new Node(1);
            Node second = new Node(2);
            Node third = new Node(3);

            list.head.next = second;
            second.next = third;   

            //this will make (1 -> 2 -> 3)
        }
}
```

**BeginnersBook Approach:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedList{
    public static void main(String args[]){

      LinkedList<Integer> list=new LinkedList<Integer>();

      //Adding elements to the Linked list
      list.add(1);
      list.add(2);
      list.add(3);
    } 
 }
```

Comment: I will suggest you for manual `LinkedList` there are some tutorials available on Youtube if you go through it, you will get clear idea of it [here you find one demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMIq13-FZSE) similar to GeeksforGeeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is

**GeeksforGeeks** teaches you manual implementation of Linked List, but you need basic knowledge in java because you will have a hard time understanding it.

**BeginnersBook** teaches you *Java Collections Framework*. This framework has several useful classes which have tons of useful functions which makes a programmer task super easy.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMIq13-FZSE here you can watch data structures here

Answer (score 2):

> approach in geeksforgeeks is manual linkedlist while beginnersbook is using linkedlist library, is that correct?

That's totally true.

BeginnersBook Approach describes how to use LinkedList in general regardless its internal implementation

GeeksforGeeks Approach describes how can LinkedList be implemented inside.

Comment: I guess so :) It really depends on what are you intended to learn. If you're learning how to use List and LinkedList in general - that's fine to skip implementation details. But if you're intended to understand how LinkedList can be implemented (one way linking or two way linking) - that's worth reading

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GeeksforGeeks is the manual (or "pedestrian" way), the BeginnersBook uses a library.

The GeeksforGeeks example actually teaches how to create a linked list from scratch. It is sort of the bare minimum to call a list a linked list. You need a head, and then a way to chain subsequent list elements by creating an element and then linking it somewhere in the list. In the example they are linked at the end.

BeginnersBook uses an existing java library. It teaches you nothing about how such a list works internally. The class turns a list (a bunch of things) into a linked list (a bunch of things chained/linked together), but you don't see in the example what it means to have the items linked, it only shows you how to use the library by "adding" items. The library (see https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html ) has all sorts of methods to add new items, to go the next item etc...

In terms of learning what a linked list is, the first is a better example.